# Javascript confirm for asp:ButtonColumn

Tags: javascript, asp.net, datagrid

I have a datagrid with a buttoncolumn inside which contains a done button. I'm trying to have a javascript confirm() pop up when the 'done' button is clicked.

I was able to get the confirm() to pop up but it was within datagrid and would pop up if the user clicked anywhere within the grid.

Code below

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="dgStuff" runat="server" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gridviewHead" CssClass="gridview" PagerStyle-CssClass="gridview_pager"
    AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="gridview_alter" OnItemCommand="dgStuff_ItemCommand" DataKeyField="reminderID" AllowSorting="True" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="return confirmDone(); >
        <Columns>
            <asp:HyperLinkColumn DataNavigateUrlField="id" HeaderText="Select" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="/lead.aspx?user={0}" Text="View" ></asp:HyperLinkColumn>
            <asp:ButtonColumn ButtonType="LinkButton" HeaderText="Completed" Text="Done" CommandName="Reminder" />
        </Columns>
        </asp:DataGrid>

function confirmDone() {
        return confirm("Are you sure you want to continue?")
    };
```

confirmDone(); was what I had when it would be open anywhere clicked in the datagrid.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by having it recognize the text of the link to bring up the confirm()

```
$('#dgStuff').click(function (e) {
        var txt = $(e.target).text();
        if (txt == 'Done') {
            return confirm("Are you sure you want to continue?");
        } else {

        }

    });
```